Yolo11 Image Detection is great but mouse won't move to the location of found image and click it
What I want to happen is, detect those images based on my downloaded file from YOLOv11 Colab. Then once detected, move mouse over or cursor and click it. Here is the code.
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load the YOLOv8 model with your custom-trained weights (best11.pt)
model = YOLO("best11.pt")

# Flag to control the start/stop of detection
running = False

# Define class names (assuming the model uses these labels)
class_names = {0: "yellow warning", 1: "red warning", 2: "refill warning"}

# Function to take a screenshot, detect objects, and click on the center of each detection
def detect_and_click():
    screenshot_path = "screenshot.png"
    
    while running:
        # Capture a screenshot using pyautogui
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        screenshot_np = np.array(screenshot)  # Convert to numpy array
        screenshot_np = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot_np, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)  # Convert to BGR format for OpenCV

        # Use the model to detect objects in the screenshot
        results = model(screenshot_np)  # Pass the numpy array directly

        if results:
            print("Detection results found.")
        else:
            print("No results detected.")

        # Loop through detected objects and get their bounding box coordinates
        for result in results:
            for box in result.boxes:
                if box.xyxy.shape[0] >= 4:
                    # Get the normalized coordinates of the bounding box
                    x_min = box.xyxy[0].item()
                    y_min = box.xyxy[1].item()
                    x_max = box.xyxy[2].item()
                    y_max = box.xyxy[3].item()

                    # Convert the normalized coordinates to pixel coordinates
                    img_height, img_width, _ = screenshot_np.shape  # Get image dimensions (height, width)
                    x_min_pixel = int(x_min * img_width)
                    y_min_pixel = int(y_min * img_height)
                    x_max_pixel = int(x_max * img_width)
                    y_max_pixel = int(y_max * img_height)

                    # Calculate the center of the bounding box (in pixels)
                    x_center = (x_min_pixel + x_max_pixel) / 2
                    y_center = (y_min_pixel + y_max_pixel) / 2

                    # Get the class label and name
                    class_id = int(box.cls[0].item())  # Class ID of the detected object
                    class_name = class_names.get(class_id, "Unknown")

                    # Debugging: Print the coordinates and class name
                    print(f"Class: {class_name}")
                    print(f"Bounding Box Coordinates (pixel): x_min={x_min_pixel}, y_min={y_min_pixel}, x_max={x_max_pixel}, y_max={y_max_pixel}")
                    print(f"Center Coordinates (pixel): x_center={x_center}, y_center={y_center}")

                    # Check if the coordinates are valid for screen resolution
                    screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()
                    print(f"Screen resolution: {screen_width}x{screen_height}")
                    if 0 <= x_center <= screen_width and 0 <= y_center <= screen_height:
                        # Move the cursor to the center of the bounding box
                        print(f"Moving cursor to: {x_center}, {y_center}")
                        try:
                            pyautogui.moveTo(x_center, y_center, duration=0.5)  # Move to the center of the bounding box with a small delay
                            print(f"Cursor moved to: {x_center}, {y_center}")
                            
                            # Add a small delay to ensure the cursor has moved
                            time.sleep(0.2)

                            # Click 10 times at the detected center
                            for _ in range(10):
                                print(f"Clicking at: {x_center}, {y_center}")
                                pyautogui.click()  # Left click 10 times
                                time.sleep(0.1)  # Small delay between clicks
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(f"Error moving cursor or clicking: {e}")
                    else:
                        print(f"Invalid coordinates: {x_center}, {y_center}")
                
                time.sleep(0.5)  # Add delay between frames for stability

# Function to monitor F1 and F2 keys
def monitor_keys():
    global running
    print("Press F1 to start and F2 to stop.")
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('F1') and not running:
            print("Detection started...")
            running = True
            detect_and_click()
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('F2') and running:
            print("Detection stopped.")
            running = False

# Start monitoring keys
monitor_keys()

I used the F1 and F2 to test run it live.
I ran it. This is the result.
Press F1 to start and F2 to stop.
Detection started...

0: 384x640 1 yellow warning, 145.0ms
Speed: 2.6ms preprocess, 145.0ms inference, 1.5ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
Detection results found.

0: 384x640 1 yellow warning, 107.7ms
Speed: 2.0ms preprocess, 107.7ms inference, 1.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
Detection results found.

0: 384x640 1 yellow warning, 102.9ms
Speed: 2.2ms preprocess, 102.9ms inference, 0.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
Detection results found.

0: 384x640 1 yellow warning, 106.3ms
Speed: 1.3ms preprocess, 106.3ms inference, 0.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
Detection results found.

0: 384x640 (no detections), 102.2ms
Speed: 2.7ms preprocess, 102.2ms inference, 1.5ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
Detection results found.

0: 384x640 (no detections), 103.2ms
Speed: 1.4ms preprocess, 103.2ms inference, 0.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
Detection results found.

My goal is, once image is detected, move mouse over to that location of found image and click it. It only detects and not click it.

What is the purpose of this check: if box.xyxy.shape[0] >= 4? It will always return False and the full code block # Loop through detected objects and get their bounding box coordinates will never be processed. box.xyxy.shape always returns torch.Size([1, 4])
